# Error with Custom Admin Screen in iframe Thickbox

Tags: plugin-development, admin, thickbox, iframe

I have a plugin that adds a new admin screen in an iframe. I created a PHP file in my plugin, and I put a link with a class of Thickbox to that. Everything works just fine, but it produces a PHP error when WP_DEBUG is set to true. Looking at the WordPress source code, there's no way around the error if I put a PHP from outside `/wp-admin/` directly in an iframe.

> Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in .../wp-includes/vars.php on line 28

It happens because WordPress is running regex on the web address to extract the file name to set the $pagenow variable, but it assumes the file will be in /wp-admin/. Since it's not, there are no matches.

Here is [the plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/subordinate-post-type-helpers/). The file is `children.php`.

Is there a better way to create a custom admin screen that can be included in an iframe Thickbox that runs through a `/wp-admin/` file?

Comment: Dion Hulse pointed me in the right direction on [Twitter](https://twitter.com/dd32/status/264760532920315906). I'll post a full write-up soon. [wp-admin/admin-post.php + add_action + iframe_header() + echo body + iframe_footer()]

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I've tried interpreting Dion Hulse's directions a few different ways, but can't get this to work. It's one of those things that it seems the WordPress team never intended to be extended.

Comment: @MattVanAndel, working sample bellow ;)

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question.
Investigating it, I've found a [[wp-hackers] thread](http://lists.automattic.com/pipermail/wp-hackers/2010-January/029708.html) by the same Dion Hulse which gives a bit more of information.

First, a testing page with a simple link which will open another admin page in a thickbox.

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'wpse_71437_admin_submenu');

function wpse_71437_admin_submenu() 
{
    add_menu_page(
        'TB', 
        '<span style="color:#e57300;">Thickbox</span>', 
        'edit_pages', 
        'open_hidden_page_in_thickbox', 
        'wpse_71437_submenu_page',
        '', // no icon
        1 // create before Dashboard menu item
    );
}

function wpse_71437_submenu_page() 
{
    wp_enqueue_style('thickbox');
    wp_enqueue_script('thickbox');
    ?>
    <div id="icon-upload" class="icon32"></div><h2>Thickbox</h2>
    <br><br>
    <a href="#" id="open-tb">Click Here</a>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {   
        jQuery("#open-tb").click(function() {                 
            tb_show("", "index.php?page=video_page_hidden&TB_iframe=true");
            return false;
        });
    });             
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

Now, the page that will be opened in the thickbox. It's parent is defined as `null`, so it doesn't show up in the menu. And the callback is an empty function, if accessed directly nothing appears.

```
/**
 * Add a hidden and empty submenu page
 */
add_action('admin_menu', 'wpse_71437_admin_menu');

function wpse_71437_admin_menu() 
{
    add_submenu_page(
        null, // doesn't show up in the menu, attached to "index.php" (not sure why)
        'Video', 
        'Video', 
        'edit_pages', 
        'video_page_hidden', 
        'wpse_71437_menu_options'
    );
}

function wpse_71437_menu_options() { /* Print nothing */ }
```

And finally, the trick!
Intercept the hidden page load and print some `iframe` content:

```
/**
 * Intercept our hidden/empty page and print the Thickbox content
 */
add_action( 'load-dashboard_page_video_page_hidden', 'wpse_71437_intercept_thickbox' ); 

function wpse_71437_intercept_thickbox() 
{ 
    iframe_header(); 
    echo '<iframe width="100%" height="380px" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/cL6qe0b-_BA" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
    iframe_footer(); 
    exit; //Die to prevent the page continueing loading and adding the admin menu's etc. 
}
```