# how to use thickbox in admin?

Tags: plugin-development, wp-admin, thickbox

I would like to show my retrieved content form my classes method in thickbox. How could I do this? I have been adding the proper id to my desired hyperlink but all of the admin body is getting parsed inside of the thickbox.

```
<a href="?page=blahblah&TB_iframe=true&width=600&height=550" class="thickbox">Click</a>


class myAdmin {

    public function __construct() {

    }

    public function myfunction() {    
        echo '<div class="css_class">The content of my thickbox</div>';    
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Below, an example of what's needed to use ThickBox.

```
<?php     
wp_enqueue_style('thickbox');
wp_enqueue_script('thickbox');    
?>

<a href="#" id="taxonomy_banner_image" class="taxonomy_banner_image"> 
Click Here
</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {   
    jQuery("#taxonomy_banner_image").click(function() {                 
        tb_show("", "filename?TB_iframe=true");
        return false;
    });
});             
</script>
```

`tb_show` parameters:

1. **title** of the box.
2. **url** of file and with parameter `iframe=true`

I think this will give you an idea how to use the ThickBox. If you face any problem, let me know.

Comment: thank you for your feedback, but still having problem to do not have all the content of admin page wrapped

Comment: @fefe and Arvind, take a look at [this Answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/76947/12615), you need to intercept the thickbox and add  `iframe_header()`, `iframe_footer()` and `exit`.

Comment: You can also use the function `add_thickbox()` as alternative to enqueue the script and style. Is a little bid easier and fast forward.

Comment: I what to pass dynamic content with parameter, how can i do it?

Comment: Please can you explain in detail which parameters you want to pass?

Comment: @Arvind Pal Could you please let me know how do I use jQuery and CSS inside Thickbox? The base page where Thickbox is shown already has jQuery enqueued but that's not usable inside Thickbox.

Any help is much appreciated.